# Using 'this' when initializing an instance variable in java?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization, this

I've seen `this` used when declaring an instance variable in IB's API, but this seems like a bad idea. Is assignment guaranteed to occur after `this` has been fully constructed? Does it matter?

I thought that instance variables were initialized prior to the constructor since they can be used by the constructor. Is there some exception if `this` is used?

If it somehow works, it doesn't seem like a good idea -  is `second` available to `FirstClass`'s constructor? If so, is `SecondClass` constructed prior to `FirstClass`? Which means that `num` ends up being 3 and `i` is 10? Or will there be a runtime error? Is there even any guarantee either way?

```
public class FirstClass {

    SecondClass second = new SecondClass(this);
    public int i = 3;

    FirstClass(){
        i = second.DoSomething();
    }
}

public class SecondClass{

    private int num = 10;

    SecondClass(FirstClass first){
        num = first.i;
    }
    public int DoSomething(){
        return num;
    }
    ...
}
```

I'd like to think that IB have a pretty solid team of developers and know what they're doing. What do you think:

1. Can `this` be used initializing instance variables?
2. Should it be done?

**EDIT**

The answer is yes there is a guaranteed result (for now - but read on...), but no it shouldn't be done since its easy to inadvertently make changes to the code that could change this 'guaranteed' result.

I now know that when constructing a new object (such as `FirstClass`) the JVM:

1. Allocates memory for all the instance variables of this class and all its superclasses.
2. Initializes all the variables with default values
3. "Properly" initializes all the variables *in textual order* starting from its highest superclasses (i.e. Object) and finishing with this class - so `second` is initialized (i.e. constructed) prior to i being initialized to 3.
4. If any of these "proper" initializations call another method or another constructor, this is done *before* the first constructor is invoked - so `second` is constructed and returned prior to the `FirstClass` constructor being run.
5. If another constructor is invoked by instance initialization (such as in item 4), it goes through the same process from item 1 (memory allocation, initialization etc)

The reason doing this is bad is that the 'guaranteed' result can change in two ways:

1. If the source code order is changed (e.g. if `i` is initialized before `second` is constructed) the result will change. It would be easy not to notice this.
2. If someone subclasses our class (or classes), they may not be aware of the delicate balance and could change something that affects the result when overwriting.

So it looks like IB's API suffers from this delicacy, which I will have to now keep in mind.

Thanks to Emil H's answer and his direction to this article which ultimately led me to my understanding above: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html - this is highly recommended reading.

Also thanks to Alexander Drobyshevsky who made a very similar point in his answer.

Comment: Can't you simply test this and see the result?

Comment: Sure, one time. But how do I know its not a random race condition that could once in a while perform differently? I'd like to know if there are any certainties - and if so, if its ok to use or should it be avoided for "style" reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting question. What happens in the case you describe is that when you call `new FirstClass()` the class loader looks up that class and loads it if its not loaded already. Then it seems to create a instance of `FirstClass` where all the fields have their default values, e.g. second is null and i is 0.

Then it the classloader loads `SecondClass`. An instance of `SecondClass` is created and initialized which sets the `num` field to 10. Then the constructor get's called passing in the `FirstClass` instance (the fields  have the values that have been initialized up to that point). So the value of `num` in `SecondClass` will be set to 0 in the constructor.

After the `SecondClass` constructor is finished the object get's assigned to the `second` field in the `FirstClass` (which is still being initialized). After that `i` gets initialized to 3. Now the constructor of `FirstClass` get's called and i is assigned the return value of `DoSomething()` which in this case will be 0.

For further reference you could look at: http://www.artima.com/designtechniques/initializationP.html
It gives a description of object initalization.

**TL;DR**
So to answere your questions:

1. Yes, `this` can be used when initializing instance variables.
2. It should be avoided, since if someone moves the fields around (for instance sorting them) could change the behaviour of your class, which would not be expected.

Comment: Great article, it helped me understand how it works so I'm selecting your answer - I still have <15 rep so can't upvote yet.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, sometimes you **have to** use this, for example when a variable given through the Constructor is called as same as a instance variable:

```
int count;
public Test(int count){  
    this.count = count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `this` (being internally a "pointer" to the object in construction) can be used in a constructor.

A stupid example could be a self refering class

```
class MySelf {
    Myself _me;
    public MySelf() { _me = this; }
}
```

And there are more realistic examples. Imagine that you want a class to represent a mathematical graph, that you would initialize with a single element connected to itself.

Comment: This is the "this escaping the constructor" problem - it can be used by another thread before its finished constructing, which can (and should?) be avoided e.g. by using static factory methods that return a fully constructed instance. I want to know if its different when using `this` in the variable declaration - outside of the constructor. There are two question: Can it be done (and to what effect)? And should it be done?

Comment: The question was about using `this` when initializing instance valiables, not about it's use in the constructor...

Answer (score 0):

this has two possible variations in Java;
first, is when you wish to refer to a global variable (from an outer scope). e.g:

```
class First {

    private int x;

    public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x; // outer x is equal to the parameter
    }

}
```

another use, is to refer to the current object's constructor. e.g:

```
public Color {

    private int red, green, blue;

    public void Color(int r, int g, int b) {
    red = red;
    green = g;
    blue = b;
    }

    public void setColor(int r, g, b) {
    this(r,g,b);
    } 

}
```

By calling this(1,2,3) with 3 parameters to tell the compiler you wish to refer to the constructor that takes 3 parameters.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

At first, its a bad way to do so. You have to avoid these constructions: using not completely initialized variables. 
Some time it might be helpful to use "Template Method" design pattern.

Exactly for your example, in this case, result value of i = 0 after FirstClass constructor have executed; And it depends on order of assignment of i in FirstClass. If you change assignment order by next way:

```
public int i = 3;
SecondClass second = new SecondClass(this); // just order changed
```

You get answer i = 3 after FirstClass constructor have executed.

this - is only reference to current class instance. Its already exist at a time your class instance variable are beginning initializing. At first all variables have their default values (object is null, int is 0, etc.). At second are initialized all simple assignments like "int i = 3", after that executing super constructor of your current class and finally executing constructor of current class. Simple variables are initialized by order in the class up to down, BUT you should not rely on it.

Comment: Thanks, I'd upvote your help if I could but I still have <15 reputation.